# Image not saving after updating pixel color in PIL

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I've generated barcode images in PNG format using HuBarcode, and have modified them to add a border of `rgb(150, 150, 150)` in hopes of accessing the pixels of that color to change them. I can access the pixel and get confirmation via `print` that the color is being changed, but when I open the image file, nothing has changed. The pixels are still `rgb(150, 150, 150)`. Here's a code snippet I'm using. I can add more of my code if it will be helpful:

```
def add_colored_border(self, barcode):
  img = Image.open(barcode)
  img = img.convert('RGB')
  px = img.load()
  for x in range(img.size[0]):
    for y in range(img.size[1]):
      pixel = px[x, y]
      if pixel == (150, 150, 150):  
        pixel = (0, 0, 255)
  img.save('testing.png')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to copy the modified pixel value back into the pixel access object. Eg,

```
if px[x, y] == (150, 150, 150):
    px[x, y] = (0, 0, 255)
```

There's an example in the old PIL docs for [Image.load()](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.load).

If you're modifying a lot of pixels, you may wish to use [getdata()](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getdata) and [putdata()](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.putdata). Those links are to the docs of the new fork of PIL known as Pillow, but those functions are also available in the old PIL.

---

```
pixel = px[x, y]
if pixel == (150, 150, 150):  
    pixel = (0, 0, 255)
```

doesn't do what you want because `pixel = (0, 0, 255)` creates a new tuple and binds that to the name `pixel`, it doesn't modify the tuple in the PixelAccess object at `px[x, y]`.

Tuples are immutable, so they *can't* be modified - if you want to change them you need to replace them with a new tuple. Python *does* let you modify *lists* in a way *similar* to what you were trying, since lists *are* mutable. To make this work, we need to use a list of lists, we can't use a simple list of integers or strings since Python integers and strings are immutable.

```
a = [[i] for i in range(5)]
print a
b = a[2]
print b
b[0] = 7
print b
print a
```

**output**

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]
[2]
[7]
[[0], [1], [7], [3], [4]]
```

This works because I'm modifying the contents of `b`. But if I do

```
c = a[3]
c = [11]
print a
```

**output**

```
[[0], [1], [7], [3], [4]]
```

Now `a` is unchanged. The assignment to `c` binds a new list to `c`, it doesn't touch the `a[3]` object that `c` was previously bound to.

For more on this important topic please see the excellent illustrated article [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by SO member Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Awesome! That works perfectly. Why doesn't using ```pixel = px[x, y]``` to access the pixel work like I have it above?

Comment: I think the answer is misleading because it has nothing to do with lists vs. tuples.  If everything would have been lists the code would read `pixel = 0, 0, 255]` and still wouldn't work because rebinding the name of the loop variable has just an effect on exactly that binding and not any other object regardless of type or (im)mutability.

Comment: @BlackJack: Well, I did mention the stuff about the new tuple being bound to the name `pixel`, but I agree that the 2nd addendum to my answer could be a little misleading, so I've modified it.

Comment: @BlackJack: Is that better?

Comment: IMHO not really because it is not about _„modify the tuple in the PixelAccess object at px[x, y]”_ but about modifying the `PixelAccess` object. We don't even know if that object stores tuples.  It is in fact very unlikely it really does contain tuples and not some memory efficient mutable representation of the pixel data in a C array.  So tuples don't really have anything to do with the source of the problem.  If index access and assignement would return and expect lists, the problem would be exactly the same.

Comment: Point taken about we don't really know how a `PixelAccess` object works. OTOH, the `PixelAccess` object can obviously be modified, so from Python's perspective, the `PixelAccess` object itself is mutable. However, if you do `type(px[x, y])` the result is `tuple`.

Comment: @BlackJack: If the items in the `PixelAccess` object were lists, then we could do `pixel=px[x,y]; pixel[:]=[0, 0, 255]` and `px[x,y]` _would_ be changed. Agreed?

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the update. Definitely helped me get a better understanding of what's going on.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Agreed.  For the we don't really know the guts of a `PixelAccess` object: One could start digging into [pixel_access_getitem()](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/_imaging.c#L2830) and [pixel_access_setitem()](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/_imaging.c#L2840) :-)

Comment: @BlackJack: Although that's very nice looking C source, I really couldn't be bothered trawling through it. I'm content to just treat the `PixelAccess` items as "tuple-like" entities: if it quacks like a tuple, it's a tuple. :)